# Why inside of a trigger the code before raise_application_error isn't executed?

Tags: sql, database, plsql, triggers

IF I create this trigger, then the error is raised when drop or truncate is used on tables, but there is nothing inserted into logTable, but if I delete RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR... then the values are inserted into logTable, but the drop/truncate are executed too. Why? How can I avoid drop/truncate on Schema (If I use instead of trigger, it is fired only if owner of the schema is dropping/truncating something).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE DROP OR TRUNCATE ON DATABASE
DECLARE
username varchar2(100);
BEGIN
  IF ora_dict_obj_owner = 'MySchema' THEN
    select user INTO username from dual; 
    INSERT INTO logTable VALUES(username , SYSDATE);
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001,'ERROR, YOU CAN NOT DELETE THIS!!');
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Out of interest, what is the purpose of `select user INTO username from dual`?

Comment: The purpose is to add into a log table the username of who wanted to drop/truncate a table from MySchema.

Comment: But you already know `user`. The query just seems to copy it into a variable with a slightly different name. Now `username` has the same value as `user`. It doesn't seem to give you anything you didn't already know.

Comment: If I have, for example, two users who have access to the same schema and someone is trying to drop a table, then in log table I have the username and time when he tried to drop the table.

Comment: But you can't just `insert into logTable values (user, sysdate)`? There has to be a second variable and a query to populate it?

Comment: I didn’t know that user is already defined. What is why I queried it.

Comment: If `user` wasn't defined, then I can't see how querying `dual` would populate it. Nothing you query from dual is actually stored in dual.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will change this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/transact.htm#CNCPT1115):

> **Statement-Level Atomicity**
>
> Oracle Database supports statement-level atomicity, which means that a SQL statement is an atomic unit of work
>   and either completely succeeds or completely fails.
>
> A successful statement is different from a committed transaction. A
>   single SQL statement executes successfully if the database parses and
>   runs it without error as an atomic unit, as when all rows are changed
>   in a multirow update.
>
> If a SQL statement causes an error during execution, then it is not
>   successful and so all effects of the statement are rolled back. This
>   operation is a **statement-level rollback**.

The procedure is a PL/SQL statement, it is atomic, if you raise an error within the procedure, then the whole procedure fails and Oracle performs a rollback of all the changes done by this procedure.

---

But you can create a procedure with [AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION Pragma](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/autotransaction_pragma.htm#LNPLS01302) in order to bypass this behaviour, in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE logtable(
   username varchar2(200),
   log_date date
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE log_message( username varchar2 ) IS
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO logtable( username, log_date ) VALUES ( username, sysdate );
  COMMIT;
END;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE DROP OR TRUNCATE ON DATABASE
DECLARE
username varchar2(100);
BEGIN
  IF ora_dict_obj_owner = 'TEST' THEN
    log_message( user );
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001,'ERROR, YOU CAN NOT DELETE THIS!!');
  END IF;
END;
```

---

And now:

```
drop table table1;

ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-20001: ERROR, YOU CAN NOT DELETE THIS!!
ORA-06512: at line 6
00604. 00000 -  "error occurred at recursive SQL level %s"
*Cause:    An error occurred while processing a recursive SQL statement
           (a statement applying to internal dictionary tables).
*Action:   If the situation described in the next error on the stack
           can be corrected, do so; otherwise contact Oracle Support.

select * from logtable;

USERNAME  LOG_DATE
--------  -------------------
TEST      2018-04-27 00:16:34
```